# Java - Mapping a description to a word with Map/HashMap

Tags: java, dictionary

I'm working on a small project in which I want the following to happen: I want to be able to give descriptions to words in such a way that I am able to get both pieces of information later on. Using a String array seems like it would be time consuming, and, by the way I'm interpreting what I'm reading, using the following piece of code only gives me the second written information, which is "Example Description.", because it maps the second value to the first "value" (which is a "key").

```
Map<String, String> exampleDictionaryThing = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
    put("Example Word", "Example Description.");
}};
```

Just to make sure I'm understood, as English isn't really my best language, I'm trying to make a bunch of dictionary-like things where I'm able to grab both pieces of information, the two pieces of info. being a word and a description for it, but doing a bunch of String array's would A) take a lot of time and B) would be, what seems to me, an incredibly inefficient way of going about this issue.

Anybody have any ideas?

**Update #1**

I knew my wording would cause confusion; sorry xD. From what I've read on how I'm going about this, the line of code I've given above only allows me access to the "Example Description." line if I call the get() function. What I need is something to store two Strings and give me access to both (hopefully) without using a String array. My question is: How would I go about storing two Strings in that fashion?

Comment: First, there are no `String[]` in sight.  Second, what you describe (and agree to being an ideal solution) is what you have implemented - a `Map` of `String` keywords to `String` meanings.  That said, I'm unclear as to what your question is - are you wondering if this is ideal?  We can't answer that since we don't know the full context of what you're doing.  Why not give it a try and see how it works out for you?

Comment: You can iterate over the entries in a `Map`.

Comment: Can you formulate your question in one line? I have no idea what it is your asking.

Comment: Your thinking is fine. That's what I would do. You can iterate over keys, values or entries of a Map as easily as iterating over a List or Set.

Comment: How do you want to navigate through your data? Both ways (reverse lookup)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have

```
    HashMap<String, String> mp = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

which is properly populated (basically in the way you described), you can do the following in order to iterate through it (this way you have both the key and the value in your loop):

```
    for (String word : mp.keySet()){
        System.out.println("Word: [" + word + "]; Word Description: [" + mp.get(word) + "].");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "get both pieces of information later on" as you say, maybe you should take a look at Guava's BiMap. This data structure would allow you to recover the description given the word, or the opposite.

http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html